# Full of stars: What is the last location I missed?

Tags: full-of-stars

It shows that I'm 94% complete and below shows what I have:

- homeworld
- Arcadia-1
- Ares Omega
- New Tokyo
- distress signal
- slave destination
- Q-COS
- corporate battlefield
- tortuga station
- Domsky's location
- vivid nebula
- Rift floater nest
- space telescope
- forgotten temple
- Heaven's Gate
- Blue Sector

My blue sector is at Lv2 and only 1 (the basic one) character I can play with.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last location is the Dragon's Eye. To find it you need to get Blue Sector to level 3, then you'll be able to look for the last specialist - Darwin. He is found at the Dragon's Eye, which is found from the Rift Floaters nest.

Comment: Dragon's Eye - edited for clarity